# Referencing a RELAX NG Schema from a XSD Schema

Tags: xsd, relaxng

I'm writing a schema in XSD, and I would like to reference the identifier element as defined in [Appendix A: The OPF Package Schema](http://www.idpf.org/epub/20/spec/OPF_2.0_latest.htm#AppendixA).

Blindly, I'm using the following

```
<xs:schema ... xmlns:opf="http://www.ipdf.org/2007/opf">
    ...
    <xs:element name="identifier" type="opf:DC.identifier-element" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
    ...
</xs:schema>
```

The goal is that definition of an `identifier` element is the same that the `opf` schemas definition of the `identifier` element.  I'm just not sure about targeting the type in RELAX NG from XSD Schema.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to provide an XSD version of the opf schema, to allow an XSD validator to check the constraints in the type.